# Maven snapshot dependency is incorrectly uploaded to a release repository. Can I still download it?

Tags: maven, nexus

I need a third party application as a dependency in my project. The dependency is uploaded into a **release repository** but with **snapshot version** (4.2.0-M8-20190205.102025-530).

The folder structure of the repository looks like this (replaced real project details with fantasy names):

nexusserver/repository/releases/shark/cat/dog/animal-project/4.2.0-M8-20190205.102025-530/animal-project-4.2.0-M8-20190205.102025-530.pom

Hence mvn clean install fails:

- It tries to download the dependency with the wrong URL: mynexusserver.com/repository/releases/shark/cat/dog/animal-project/**4.2.0-M8-SNAPSHOT**/animal-project-4.2.0-M8-20190205.102025-530.pom
- Then it simply fails because of the version policy:version policy:
  RELEASE does not allow version: 4.2.0-M8-20190205.102025-530

I set up my pom like this:

```
    <repository>
        <id>animal-repo</id>
        <name>Animal project repository.</name>
        <url>https://mynexusserver.com/repository/releases</url>
    </repository>

    ...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>shark.cat.dog</groupId>
        <artifactId>animal-project</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0-M8-20190205.102025-530</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
```

I understand the problem and the roots of the problem, but I can not contact the other guys nor modify the repository. So I am looking for a workaround that can be applied with Maven. I'd really appreciate any idea!

Thank you.

Comment: Please show your settings.xml and full pom file...

Comment: What version of NXRM is this for?  What's the release policy on your proxy?  Releases?